# How do I replace Unix timestamp to other date function in aws sql

Tags: amazon-web-services

```
CAST(((unix_timestamp(closed_dt_ts)-unix_timestamp(creation_dt_ts))60/60/24) AS decimal (10,2))
```

I need to replace the Unix timestamp function

I have tried using cast function with datediff it gives error as cannot cast type records to numeric

Comment: What is "aws sql"?